# Properly mocking gcs Bucket and Blob in pytest MagicMock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, google-cloud-storage, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm trying to write test for this function. I'd like not to rely on real gcs object, but mock the objects.

```
# gcs_blobs.py file
from google.cloud import storage
        
    def check_existing_blobs(new_blob_names: list[str], bucket: storage.Bucket) -> list[storage.Blob]:
        # Check if any of the new blobs exists already on bucket
        current_blobs = [blob for blob in bucket.list_blobs()]
        existing_blobs = []
        for blob_name in new_blob_names:
            for blob in current_blobs:
                if blob_name == blob.name:
                    existing_blobs.append(blob)
        return existing_blobs
```

As I understand correctly, I should

- mock Bucket.list_blobs() method so that it would return list of mocked Blob objects
- mock Blob instance 'name' attribute so that it would return name I want

I'm trying to do that with no success. In test code below, `check_existing_blobs(new_blob_names, bucket)` returns empty list. In this case I'd like it to return blob with name *blob1*.
How do I do that properly?

Would using 'side_effect' on blob.name allow me to return names from the provided 'existing_blob_names' list in consecutive calls to blob.name?

How to do this assertion properly, with list of blobs with names from the list?

```
# test_blobs.py file
from unittest.mock import Mock, MagicMock

import pytest
from google.cloud import storage

from .gcs_files import (
    check_existing_blobs
)


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "new_blob_names,existing_blob_names",
    [
        (
            ['blob1'],
            ['blob1', 'blob2'],
        ),
    ]
)
def test_contains_existing_files(mocker, new_blob_names, existing_blob_names):
    
    storage.Bucket = MagicMock()
    bucket = storage.Bucket()

    storage.Blob = MagicMock()
    blob = storage.Blob()
    
    #mocker.patch.object(blob, "name", new="blob_name") # after that blob.name prints "blob_name"
    mocker.patch.object(blob, "name", side_effect=existing_blob_names)

    print(blob.name) # output: <MagicMock name='name' id='139862698975120'>

    # in place of '???' it should be mock of storage.Blob instance which .name returns one of the blob names
    # assert check_existing_blobs(new_blob_names, bucket) == [???]
```

Also please let me know if I should split this question to subproblems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend not using `MagicMock()` for this.  Instead, just make a new class that has the behavior you want:

```
class MockBucket:

    def __init__(self, names):
        self.blobs = [MockBlob(x) for x in names]

    def list_blobs(self):
        return self.blobs

class MockBlob:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I'd also recommend not assigning to `storage.Bucket` or `storage.Blob`.  These assignments won't be reverted when the test function ends, so they have great potential to interfere with later tests.  In fact, the purpose of `mocker.patch` and `mocker.patch.object` is to avoid this kind of assignment.  In your case, though, there's no reason to patch anything, because the code being tested doesn't rely on any global variables.

Comment: As I understand, this assignment like `storage.Bucket = MagicMock()` lasts only for duration of a single test, right? Just thinking, that might be actually something that I expect. Not sure if I have a situation here where it could be unwanted.

Comment: If you did `mocker.patch('storage.Bucket')`, that would only last for the duration of a single test.  But if you just do a normal assignment like `storage.Bucket = MagicMock()`, that will last until python exits.  You could test this by checking the value of `storage.Bucket` in an unrelated test.

Comment: Solution with new classes works for me. I've also used `mocker.patch('storage.Client', MockClient)` with my `MockClient` class, to test some other code that uses `storage.Client`. It also works when patch is made in a fixture in conftest file. As You said, best to use `mocker.patch` instead of assigning, not to interfere with other fixtures from conftest.